# Cómo reducir la inicialización de una variable dentro de una condicional

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy bifurcando una acción en mi app. Quiero que se cargue al inicio al inicio un lenguaje, otro o el que tiene por defecto el dispositivo. Para esto debo cambiar las propiedades y pues se ve mal esa repetición dentro de una condicional. Quiero saber si existe forma de hacer esto que propongo debajo. Este es mi código actual:

```
var actualLanguage = await session.language;
if (actualLanguage == "device") {
  await translator.init(
    localeType: LocalizationDefaultType.device,
    languagesList: <String>['en', 'es'],
    assetsDirectory: 'assets/lang/',
  );
} else {
  await translator.init(
    language: actualLanguage,
    languagesList: <String>['en', 'es'],
    assetsDirectory: 'assets/lang/',
  );
}
```

Quiero saber si hay forma de reunir todas esa propiedades que repito y agregarlas como con un map.
Algo así por ejemplo:

```
props = {a: "a", b: "b"};
if (actualLanguage == "device") {
  await translator.init(
    ...props
  );
} else {
  await translator.init(
    language: actualLanguage,
    ...props
  );
}
```

Comment: Si lo único que cambia es el `localeType`, podrías utilizar un ternario para devolver lo que te interesa ahí -> `localeType: (actualLanguage == "device") ? LocalizationDefaultType.device : actualLanguage`. Así no necesitas ni el `if/else` ni nada.

Comment: cambian más propiedades solo hice un resumen, no quiero repetir condicionales durante 6 o 7 props

Answer (score 0):

una posible solución sería encapsular esa función de inicialización en otra función de esta forma:

```
Future<void> initializeTranslator(lenguage) async {
  await translator.init(
    language: lenguage,
    languagesList: <String>['en', 'es'],
    assetsDirectory: 'assets/lang/',
  );
}
```

Para luego solo tener que llamar esa función:

```
if (actualLanguage == "device") {
  await initializeTranslator(LocalizationDefaultType.device);
} else {
  await initializeTranslator(lenguage);
}
```